# Angular CLI - Encrypted varaible with secret Key: jwt-simple doesn't work

Tags: encryption, webpack, jwt, angular-cli, access-token

I would like to encode a variable (accessToken for example here) but I'm using Angular CLI and so, Webpack, I wanted to use jwt-simple like this:

```
const encryptedAccessToken = jwt.encode(user.accessToken, APP_SECRET)
```

I have imported the module jwt-simple with :

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
```

But then I have an error linked to the crypto module:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function
TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function
    at sign (jwt.js:177)
    at Object.jwt_encode [as encode] (jwt.js:143)
    at authentication.service.ts:41
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:141)
    at zone.js:831
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at sign (jwt.js:177)
    at Object.jwt_encode [as encode] (jwt.js:143)
    at authentication.service.ts:41
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:141)
    at zone.js:831
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
    at zone.js:834
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1388)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080
next @ core.es5.js:4503
schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3635
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3621
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:3912
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.es5.js:3844
onHandleError @ core.es5.js:3912
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:157
_loop_1 @ zone.js:666
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:675
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:603
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
invokeTask @ zone.js:1370
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1388
```

I don't know if there is another way to protect secret variables with Angular CLI, or if I can solve this crypto issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue in Angular CLI, see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548